# Redirecting stdin - C

Tags: c, linux, input, stdin

So I'm meant to accept a text file by doing the following command:

```
$ sort < list.txt
```

I understand that the list text file is being inputted to my sort program, but how do I actually use the information inside my program? How do I read it?

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    char c;   

    while (c != EOF){
        c = getchar();
        printf("%c ",c);
    }

   return (0);
}
```

Example:

```
$ ./sort.c < input.txt

./sort.c: line 3: $'\r': command not found

./sort.c: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('

'/sort.c: line 4: `int main(int argc, char** argv) {
```

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>` and read from `stdin`.

Comment: The redirection is something that takes place outside of your program.  The shell will take care of opening the `list.txt` file *before* your program starts and connects it to your program's standard input.  Your program need not do anything about it.  You'll only notice that `isatty(STDIN_FILENO)` will return 0 if you dare to ask it.

Comment: @5gon12eder Oh, I'm sure you nailed it. My comment tells *how*; your comment explains *why*, and thus is more educational. It just didn't occur to me -- I've known how redirection works for so long, it's like a fish not noticing water :)

Comment: @5gon12eder , how can I use the information in the text file though?

Comment: Now I'm really confused.  Do you know how to read from standard input without redirection, @ImBadAtProgramming?  If yes, everything is fine.  If not, do what Tom Zych says (and edit the title of your question).

Comment: @5gon12eder yes I understand how to use scanf, to store strings etc. But from this text file how would I read the information and use it to sort it?

Comment: Forget that the input is redirected from a text file.  Your program need not worry about it.  If your program works and reads from the terminal, just try typing the command shown in your question and you'll see it will work too.

Comment: Yes, @5gon12eder is right. You don't need to use `stdin`, probably. My C skills must be rustier than I thought...

Comment: @ImBadAtProgramming Pro tip: If you show us your current code, we need less guessing what your problem is.  ;-)

Comment: Ah! Your *actual* problem is that you are trying to execute your source code instead of the compiled program.

Comment: Also, your loop is bad. You need to check `c` *after* reading, and certainly not before initializing it, as you are here. Something like `while (1) {c = getchar(); if (c != EOF) printf... else break;}

Comment: Not used to having to compile since I usually run in an IDE. woops. Still doesn't fix my problem though, in the IDE it's just a program that doesn't end until I press ctrl D. For what I have to do, do I have to make a file like @Harmeet's solution suggests?

Comment: In the IDE, it's not reading from the redirected file. It's reading from the keyboard, wondering why you're not typing anything.

Comment: http://gyazo.com/1c4f7f23f2bf261f06cf11b95ce17c12 I have set the < input.txt here, it's in the same directory.

Comment: Also int c, not char c.

Comment: If your compiler had its' warnings turned on then it would have told you that you were using the value of 'c' before it was set to anything useful.  the function getchar() returns an int and the constant EOF is an int, (-1).  So, the comparison between (int-1)(0xFFFF) and char(0xFF) would always fail.  So the loop would never exit.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the '`<`' symbol on the command line as you have written in your post, the OS reads the file for you and gives the contents to your program via `stdin`. So, all you need to do is to read from stdin.

Here is a very simple code snippet to demonstrate -

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char line[256];
    FILE *fp = stdin;
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL) {
        printf("%s", line);
    }
}
```